# In MySQL 5.2 and greater, can triggers be added to a table after some entries have been done in the table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

We have to automate a lot of queries and the problem is, in some of them we have to first handle some base cases. And, we still want to automate a lot of work. So, is it possible to add triggers after entries have been done?